# React: How to render a list of items grouped by category (using .map)

Tags: reactjs

I have an array (myArray), stored like so (in firebase):

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "Category": "Hardware",
        "Name": "Xtreme"
    },
    {
        "id": "123",
        "Category": "Software",
        "Name": "Obsolete"
    },
    {
        "id": "12345",
        "Category": "Software",
        "Name": "V1"
    },
    {
        "id": "1234567",
        "Category": "Hardware",
        "Name": "CPU"
    }
  ]
```

I am using the following code:

```
const sorterAR = [];
  myArray.forEach((item) => {
    let cat = sorterAR.find(
      (cat) => cat.id === item.id
    );
    if (!cat) {
      cat = {
        id: item.id,
        Category: item.Category,
        items: [],
      };
      sorterAR.push(cat);
    }
    cat.items.push(item);
  });
```

And then displaying like so:

```
<div className="App">
      {sorterAR.map((cat) => (
        <>
          <div>
            <b>{cat.Category}</b>
          </div>
          <ul>
            {cat.items.map((item) => (
              <li>{item.Name}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </>
      ))}
</div>
```

This works in that it produces an output like:

```
**Hardware**
Xtreme

**Hardware**
CPU

**Software**
Obsolete

**Software**
V1
```

How do I alter this to produce the following output:

```
**Hardware**
Xtreme
CPU

**Software**
Obsolete
V1
```

So that it displays the category name and then all the items in that category, and then moves to the next one and so forth?

Comment: does order matter, like software or  hardware should come first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assumed that order doesn't matter if Hardware or Software should come first.
First I categorized the array into an object of Category objects using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).
From the resultant object you can build the JSX

```js
var data1 = [
{
    id: '1',
    Category: 'Hardware',
    Name: 'Xtreme',
},
{
    id: '123',
    Category: 'Software',
    Name: 'Obsolete',
},
{
    id: '12345',
    Category: 'Software',
    Name: 'V1',
},
{
    id: '1234567',
    Category: 'Hardware',
    Name: 'CPU',
},
];

const categorizedData = data1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
const { id, Category, Name } = curr;

if (!acc[Category]) {
    acc[Category] = {
        items: [],
    };
}
acc[Category].items.push(Name);

return acc;
}, {});

console.log(categorizedData);

Object.keys(categorizedData).map((key, index) => {
console.log(`Category: ${key}`);
categorizedData[key].items.map((item, index) =>
    console.log(`Item ${index}: ${item}`)
);
});
```

[image: Edit bold-saha-gxzh9]

Comment: Just FYI: even though you can write all this code yourself, and it's not complicated. You could also use lodash for example https://lodash.com/docs/#keyBy it contains all sorts of useful functions.

Comment: Thankyou @cmgchess - just wondering with the object.keys -> how do I use that within the return (for display)

Comment: just like how you have done. `cat.Category` is the `key`. `cat.items.map((item)` is `categorizedData[key].items.map((item, index)`

Comment: Real newbie question here @cmgchess - I can see the result via console.log(`Category: ${key}`); - but how do I actually output this on screen?

Comment: @PaulVI https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-saha-gxzh9?file=/src/index.js hope this helps. better to have a unique key for <li> otherwise console screams at you

Comment: Fantasic @cmgchess - thank you so much - can you order the output as well? Both for the Category names and the items within them?

Comment: the output is generated according to order you have in the list

Comment: @cmgchess no worries. If the list has other fields (not only Name) but say Brand and Quantity as well, how do I add that into the return?

Comment: then you can do sth like by pushing an item object like `{name:'itemname',brand:'brandname',quantity:5}` into the `items` array

Comment: @cmgchess I get The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis